# SQL Postgres using avg column as variable in outer query

Tags: sql, postgresql, average

I wrote the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT gno, avg(weight) as x
    FROM Edge
    GROUP BY gno
    HAVING avg(weight)<max(weight)/2
```

and got this (correct) table:
[image]

now i want to use the right column and find the max value there and show only that line.
how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always compose queries like this using [CTEs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html):

```
WITH averages AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT gno, avg(weight) as x
    FROM Edge
    GROUP BY gno
    HAVING avg(weight)<max(weight)/2
)
SELECT MAX(x) FROM averages;
```

(but be aware that [CTEs are optimization fences](http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-ctes-are-optimization-fences/))

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, use `order by` and `limit`:

```
SELECT gno, avg(weight) as x
FROM Edge
GROUP BY gno
HAVING avg(weight)<max(weight)/2
ORDER BY avg(weight) desc
LIMIT 1;
```

Note that when using `group by`, you don't need `select distinct`.